# how to replace Comma with "&&" in a list of equations

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a long list of equations, each one of which is separated by a comma (,) such as

```
list = {x1 + x2 == 3, y1 + y2 == 5, z1 + z2 == t1, d1 + d2 == z2};
```

I want to solve a `NMinimize[...]` problem, and I need to specify the equations in the above `list` as follows:

```
listEq = {x1 + x2 == 3 && y1 + y2 == 5 && z1 + z2 == t1 && 
d1 + d2 == z2};
```

I could not find a way to replace the commas with `&&`. I tried the following,

```
Replace[list,","->"&&"]
```

It seems that the term `&&` is not recognized.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure you need to replace them? Tried it both ways?

Comment: @MikeY: I tried by comma only and it does not work. Maybe my MMA version 11.3 has a different code for it. I will try it again.

Comment: Can you show an actual example? The two should be synonymous.

Comment: @MikeY: I will soon give you an example. Thanks for checking it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code

```
listEq = And @@ list
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]